# How to execute PHP and Javascript codes one by one?

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing a php file in which I want three blocks of code to be executed one by one. I want code 1 to be executed first and then code 2 and finally code 3. How can it be done?

```
<?php
code 1....
?>

<scirpt>
code 2...
</script>

<?php
code 3...
?>
```

Comment: Not like that. Have the script send a request to the server, where the server runs Code 3 when it sees the request

Comment: Your example doesn't work. PHP is being executed server-side while javascript runs client-side.